# MVC 4 with OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

**Breakdown**:

- I **created an empty MVC 4 project** and proceeded to do the website.
- Realizing I need authorization and authentication in my project, I looked around and **found OWIN** to be my solution
- Tried to download OWIN packages through NuGet, but found that the **targeting framework did not match**.
- OWIN said it needed a .NET framework of 4.5, which I'm currently at.
- Confused, I still **changed my project's .net to 4.6**, which helped me successfully download OWIN
- Tried to run project, but gave me this **error**:

  "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

  - So I changed my project back to 4.5, grudgingly uninstalled OWIN and tried to run the project, but the error still shows.

I'm at a loss with what to do now. I can't even run my project even after bringing 4.5 back. Can I keep trying  to change my .NET framework version, or at this point, should I just install a lower version of OWIN?  Thanks

**EDIT**  I have tried to reinstall newtonsoft in the package manager console through a code I found on here, which didnt work

Comment: Add Newtonsoft.Json into your project from NuGet.

Comment: your comment reminded me of a step i skipped: i did try to reinstall newtonsoft in the package manager console through a code i found on here. still didnt work

Comment: upgrade your newtonsoft.json package

Comment: @KamleshArya thank you for the suggestion, i'll try once i can

Comment: which version of Newtonsoft is referenced in your project?

Comment: @Nirman sorry for the late reply, it's v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by reverting my project back to .NET framework 4.5, and **installing an older version of OWIN**

In the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 2.1.0
```

then also add:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

to `<appSettings>` in Web.config file if errors about OwinStartupAttribute show up.

Apparently the main problem I had was because I was using VS2012, which is [not supported by NuGet 2.12](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3131), the version needed for the latest OWIN.

Thanks to everyone's help

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft just switched .Net frameworks at a certain versions of OWIN which means that you have to somehow know which version of OWIN to use with the version of the .Net framework you are using. It's a shame that Microsoft can't match the standards that most Open Source projects impose on themselves :-(